# What kind of micro processor / micro controller can run Blockchain light client?

Tags: blockchain, client

Is there any kind of `micro-processor` / `micro-controller` that can run **Blockchain light client**?

An example can be **Samsung ARTIK**: https://www.artik.io

However, it's too **big**. Is there any other similar but **smaller** micro-controller that is able to run Blockchain light client?

**P.S. 1 :** For example, I do not know `NODEMCU` and `ESP8266` are a good choice for this purpose? (example: https://hackaday.com/2018/05/02/using-blockchain-explorer-apis-on-nodemcu/)

**P.S. 2 :** The projects seem run a blockchain client on a micro-controller:

(1) [EthEmbedded](http://ethembedded.com/) 
(2) [Elkrem](https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/21/elkrem-is-a-blockchain-dev-board-for-tinkerers/?guccounter=1)
(3) [EthArmbian](https://github.com/diglos/userpatches#etharmbian)

**P.S. 3 :**  And also can we consider Raspberry PI as a `micro-rocessor` / `micro-controller`? Since apparently, it's possible to install Ethereum Blockchain on it. (more information: https://ethraspbian.com/)

Comment: Common CPUs like x86(-64) and ARM are usually classed as microprocessors, and of course people run clients on those.  So maybe you can be more specific as to what you mean, and what constraints you are looking to satisfy - physical size, power, word size (16 vs 32 bit), address space, ??

Comment: Which blockchain? The requirements will depend strongly on what kind of load it is under. Bitcoin Core can run on Raspberry Pi's, but it needs some configuration and is very slow.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille Thank you, apparently, Raspberry PI is not a micro-controller. However, for me any blockchain platform adapted for IoT is fine.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thank you, for me any small micro-controller appropriate for IoT is fine. ex. I do not know `NODEMCU` and `ESP8266` are a good choice for this purpose? Thanks

Comment: @Pieter Wuille, As an example: https://hackaday.com/2018/05/02/using-blockchain-explorer-apis-on-nodemcu/

Comment: @sas That looks like it isn't running a blockchain node at all, but just querying a central server for data. There's nothing blockchain specific about that; it's just querying an API.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille, How about [EthEmbedded](http://ethembedded.com/) ? or [Elkrem](https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/21/elkrem-is-a-blockchain-dev-board-for-tinkerers/?guccounter=1) ?

Comment: Those look like they're designed for more powerful devices like RPi or Odroid.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille , There is another project entitled. [EthArmbian](https://github.com/diglos/userpatches#etharmbian) to run `Geth` or `Parity` Ethereum clients.